# sklearn inverse_transform return huge values and drops MAE to zero

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I'm experimenting with an LSTM via Tensorflow/Keras and am having some trouble rescaling the target/predicted variables. (Well, all of them, really)

I'm using the MixMaxScaler() to scale most, but not all, of my input columns:

```
columns_to_scale = ['myColumn1', 'myColumn2', ..., 'myTarget']

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
train[columns_to_scale] = scaler.fit_transform(train[columns_to_scale])

test = test_df
test[columns_to_scale] = scaler.fit_transform(test[columns_to_scale])
```

When I train my LSTM, I get MAE of ~0.1 on the scaled target. Then, I try to rescale things by rescaling test:

```
test_y = test
test_y[columns_to_scale] = scaler.inverse_transform(test_y[columns_to_scale])
```

and by replacing the target column from test with my predicted values and rescaling:

```
test_pred = test
test_pred['myTarget'] = model_pred_output
test_pred[columns_to_scale] = scaler.inverse_transform(test_pred[columns_to_scale])
```

When I do this, a couple things go wrong:

- All rescaled columns are wildly different than their original values. (For instance, myColumn1 had an original value of 71850. After the above inverse_transform, it has a value of 3.261187e+10. This is how it is with every single column.
- Not only is my target variable and predicted variable rescaled wrong (same issue as the others, but not as huge numbers, only in the 10K range where the originals were in the hundreds), but it is giving me the exact same numbers for both the myTarget and predicted rescaled values, which then makes the rescaled MAE 0. Which, of course, is not right.

All the columns are in the same order as the scaling operation, and there are the same number in the rescaling.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For anyone else that runs into something similar, I was creating *views* of the test data, not copies.

When I set

```
test_pred = test
test_pred['myTarget'] = model_pred_output

test_y = test
```

that created a view into test, so further changes to test_pred also changed test. So, when I assigned the predicted values to test_pred['myTarget'], they also got applied to test['myTarget'], which then affected test_y.

To fix, I just had to call copy() on the original assignment:

```
test_pred = test.copy()
```

Will leave this up in case anyone wants to add or give a better explanation.